# Quaternary Sequence Generation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-systems

How can a quaternary sequence be generated without converting decimal numbers to quaternary. For example, I need to generate at n = 2 , 4^n = 16 combinations, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3eE1.png).For large n, a program that converts a decimal number to a quaternary runs for a very long time.Is there a more optimal algorithm for generating such a sequence?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the quaternary expansion of numbers below 4, in the image, are wrong

Comment: Wrong, corrected. Everything is clear without a table

Comment: Have you tried "for loops"? Something like for i = 0 to 3, for j = 0 to 3, for k = 0 to 3,...?

Answer (score 0):

$4^n$ is $100\dots$ in quaternary.
While, $4^n-1$ is $333\dots$ (one digit less than the
$100\dots$). Your table seems to list numbers from $0$ to $4^n-1$. You could generate a lexicografic (dictionary) list starting with $000\dots$ and ending $333\dots$
For example when $n=1$ then we have $0,1,2,3$.
When $n=2$ then $00,01,02,03,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23,30,31,32,33$.
When $n=3$ then we get $000,001,002,003,010,011,\dots,323,330,331,332,333$.